How to Use SSM Parameters Across Multiple Kubernetes Projects in ArgoCD Without Managing Secrets for Each Project?
I am following this AWS article to set up Cognito for my projects, which are managed by ArgoCD. I successfully configured Cognito manually by editing the listener rules of the Load Balancer. However, I am now trying to automate the process using Kubernetes manifests.
The challenge is that the documentation I am following suggests adding the client_id and client_secret in a Kubernetes Secret.yaml, which I would prefer not to do due to security reasons. I want to store these values in AWS SSM Parameter Store instead.
The issue is that using SSM Parameters requires me to add a new path in my Kubernetes project's ExternalSecret, which isn't feasible for all my projects. I am looking for a way to make the SSM parameters accessible to all my Kubernetes projects managed by ArgoCD, without having to manage secrets individually for each project.
Is there a way to globally make SSM parameters available to multiple Kubernetes projects in ArgoCD?
Any guidance or best practices would be appreciated!
What I Tried: I manually configured Cognito by editing the listener rules of the Application Load Balancer, which worked fine. To automate the setup using Kubernetes manifests, I attempted to store the client_id and client_secret in an ExternalSecret and retrieve the values from AWS SSM Parameter Store. However, this approach required adding individual SSM paths for each project, making it difficult to manage across multiple projects.
What I Expected: I expected to store the client_id and client_secret in SSM Parameter Store and retrieve them in a secure and reusable way for multiple Kubernetes projects without needing to manage separate paths for each project in the ExternalSecret configuration.
What Actually Happened: The need to add specific SSM paths for each project in the Kubernetes ExternalSecret created additional management overhead, which isn't scalable across all my projects. I'm looking for a more centralized or global way to make these parameters available across all projects

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
